# User can't see server

Tags: networking, ip

The user is reporting the issue has an IP address of 10.10.15.67/20. The server has an IP address of 10.10.16.1/20. The user's machine has an IP address of 10.10.25.197/20. Can anyone explain to me based on this why he can't get to the file? This users has full permissions.

Comment: Can you ping?....

Comment: Is there a router between them, and does it also consider these to be /20 addresses? Off topic.

Comment: Also do you have a firewall blocking access or something like fail2ban?

Answer (score 0):

The first IP address belongs to network 10.10.15. The other two, to 10.19.16.

Do the first machine not being in the same subnet cannot talk to the two others. Use ping to confirm that.

You can use the subnet calculator here: https://www.calculator.net/ip-subnet-calculator.html